# Subscribe and RSS links in tag hoverbox layout broken when the "x followers, x questions" text is too long

Tags: bug, tags, design

[image: freehand circles]

In the box which appears after hovering a tag, if the "*x* followers, *x* questions" text is too long, the "subscribe" and "rss" links change their position.

Example: [[php] tag on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info).

I think a solution to this would be to increase width of the box. It currently is 330px, I think that 350px would be enough.